# Regarding if statements in lighterHTML

Tags: javascript, lit-html

I am curious as to how to do if-statements in LighterHTML. I need to show a certain button only when a certain statement is true. This if-statements need to be done in the rendering HTML part.

```
<button onclick=${() => this.deleteAll()} class="btn btn-primary">Verwijder alle</button>
```

Could anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you provide a minimal, reproduceable example of what you have tried so far and any errors you might have encountered?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [ternary operator](https://lit-html.polymer-project.org/guide/template-reference#ifs-with-ternary-operators):

```
html`
    ${myCondition
        ? html`<button onclick=${() => this.deleteAll()} class="btn btn-primary">Verwijder alle</button>`
        : html``
    }    
`;
```

Comment: Thank you very much